# CreateProcess error=5, Access is denied when trying SparkLauncher example in Win10

Tags: java, apache-spark, ioexception

I'm getting the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "E:\Software\spark-1.6.1\bin\spark-submit.cmd": CreateProcess error=5, Access is denied
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.launcher.SparkLauncher.startApplication(SparkLauncher.java:418)
    at com.wwa.spark.poc.SimpleAppLauncher.main(SimpleAppLauncher.java:13)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=5, Access is denied
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(Unknown Source)
    ... 3 more
```

When I'm trying to run the SparkLauncher example from https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/launcher/src/main/java/org/apache/spark/launcher/package-info.java

My code is:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    SparkAppHandle handle = new SparkLauncher().setAppResource("E:/spark-poc-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar")
            .setMainClass("com.wwa.spark.poc.SimpleApp").setMaster("spark://spark1:7077").setConf(SparkLauncher.DRIVER_MEMORY, "2g")
            .startApplication();
}
```

I've tried changing the permissions on the spark-submit.cmd file, but with no luck. Then, I tried to ensure all my spark installation had the correct permissions and granted permission to run to all logged in users, but that also resulted in the error pasted above.

It works perfectly if I run spark-submit.cmd from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

I was running under Apache Spark 1.6.1, hadoop 2.6 and Scala 2.11; and hadoop client 2.6.

I replaced my Spark installation with Spark 1.6.1, Hadoop 2.4 and Scala 2.10 and it started working. After reading other forums, it seems that Hadoop 2.6 had some major refactoring and removed a few packages, such as the AWS package.